The quotient of a group acting on a prjective variety isn't Hausdorff
I'm currently reading this paper and I have a problem with the last part of page 5
It says "Assume $G$ is acting on a projective variety $X$ through the $SL$ transformations of the projective space, then the quotient $X/G$ is not Hausdorff"
Some notation:
$G$ is a reductive linear algebrac group which in this case is a subgroup of $SL(n+1,\mathbb{C})$ and $G$ acts on a projective variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$
I understand in order for the action to be Hausdorff we need $Gx \subset X$ to be compact for all $x \in X$, and if $Gx \cong G$ since $G$ is not compact this means the quotient can't be Hausdorff. but in general we have $Gx \cong G/\text{Stab}(x)$.
I don't understand why $\text{Stab}(x)$ can't be too big so that $Gx$ becomes compact, I assume this has something to do with the group action being non trivial, meaning that $\bigcap \text{stab}(x)= \emptyset$ but I don't see how to proceed.
Hints and solutions are appreciated.

hausdorf $\to$ Hausdorff (with capital H and two "f")

Yes, the claim is wrong as written, it should be read as "could be non-Hausdorff."

As you use the word "Hausdorff", I assume you use the analytic topology.
I don't think this is true in general. For example, if $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ is a linear subspace (or even $\mathbb P^n$ itself), and $G\subset \operatorname{SL}(n+1)$ is the full subgroup that fixes $X$, then
$$X/G = \operatorname{pt}.$$
A good example where this does happen is the action of $G=\mathbb C^*$ on $X = \mathbb P^2$ by
$$t.[x:y:z] = [tx:ty:z].$$
This fixes the points
$$[0:0:1] \quad\text{and}\quad [x:y:0],$$
but the orbit of a point
$[x:y:z]$ with $z\neq 0$ is not closed, as $[0:0:1]$ is in its orbit. This means the corresponding point in $X/G$ cannot be closed, and so $X/G$ cannot be Hausdorff.
